# Is there a way that I can group by records that have a "cluster" of a time difference?

Tags: sql, sql-server

For example, I have a set of log records and I want to group records together if they are less than 1 minute apart. If there is a gap of more than 1 minute between the log records in the sequence, then I want to have that be in its own separate group.

Example:

| Time | RecordType |
| --- | --- |
| 00:00:01 | A |
| 00:00:02 | A |
| 00:00:03 | B |
| 00:01:02 | A |
| 00:02:05 | A |
| 00:02:06 | B |

Then I want to create something like:

| Group # | Total Count | A Count | B Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Use `lag()` to determine the first record in each group.  Then do a cumulative sum to assign the groups.  And finally aggregate:

```
select min(time), max(time), count(*),
       sum(case when recordtype = 'A' then 1 else 0 end) as num_a,
       sum(case when recordtype = 'B' then 1 else 0 end) as num_b
from (select t.*,
             sum(case when prev_time > dateadd(minute, -1, time) then 0 else 1 end) over (order by time) as grp
      from (select t.*,
                   lag(time) over (order by time) as prev_time
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
group by grp;
```